# Missing libraries in side jars

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, war

I have 2 maven projects: 1 a jar with different dependencies and a war that include all that jar.

When I look inside the created Jar I dont see any library folder. And when I look in to the War I only see the libs that the war is using and not the libraries that the jar is using.

So where those libs come from during execution? Am I missing something about the execution phase?

**This is my Jar pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>configureUtils</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>configureUtils</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
          <version>1.10</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**This is the War pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mkyong</groupId>
    <artifactId>CounterWebApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CounterWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Unit Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>configureUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>CounterWebApp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- For Tomcat -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/CounterWebApp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: To see your pom files may be helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: I just created 2 dummy projects with your pom files. Everything runs as expected: no libs in the jar file; all the libs in the war file, i.e. for war + jar dependencies. About junit: only the version 4.11 is present. The war dependency declaration prevails. Maven 3.2.1/JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libs that are being used in the jar are managed by the parent container and should not be part of the Jar it self. This insures that Jars staying small and we can link to the same library if we used it in 2 different jars.

When installing the Jar to your local repository 2 files are being created - The Jar it self and a pom file which describes the Jar dependencies. That file was empty due to a bad maven execution.

The best way to install a jar is using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

This command. - Check how different the POM is. More info can be found [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Comment: "mvn install:install-file" is needed only for a third party jar, i.e. that is not created from one of your own local Maven projects and is not available from any public m2 repository. To install one of your own Maven projects to your local m2 repository, i.e. on the same working station, simply use "mvn install" from the project root directory. Here, start with the jar project, then keep on with the war project. Often, such projects are declared as modules of an aggregator Maven project (with "pom" as packaging), e.g. see [here](https://github.com/atao60/very-simple-maven-project-with-modules)